# Best option to host BaaS side of an Android app

Tags: android, cloud

I want to host the backend of my Android app in the cloud (a couple of **.NET web services** and a **small database**; nothing else by now; maybe a **website** if things go well).

The problem is that I'm not sure which option to use: **Google Cloud** allows PHP, Ruby, Python, Go or Java only. Then there is **Rackspace**, **Azure**, **Amazon Cloud**... I found this [list](http://www.androidbegin.com/blog/list-best-android-backend-service-baas-provider/) but... I'm a little bit overwhelmed.

I will start small, with just a few users, so by now I don't need something expensive or complicated (no big data or redundancy).

What would you recommend?

Comment: Some dummy question further: no matter which option I use, I need to register some domain to access the web app (SOAP / REST) from the android client device, right? Or am I provided with some IP / domain to refer to the app?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon offer you a free tier, may be you could use it for testing purposes
https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Thanks for your support; the problem is that it seems that Windows is not included in the software Amazon provides, and I'd like to run my web services and database using WCF and SQLServer. Mono is not an option, I've had bad experiences with it in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use Azure Mobile service. This service has the seamless integrated with project .net or Node.js backend. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started/

For testing purpose, you can use the free 1 month trial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

Comment: Thanks for the support! I have a question further: the tutorial seems to show how an Android app connects directly to a database in the cloud. I'd rather orchestrate the communication between the database and the android app using a web service which will contain some logic. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can integrate your webservice with mobile service website ,write logic code into mobile service to handler your data and store into database. See this document about how to use .net backend project :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/

Comment: Thx a lot, I'll give it a try this weekend ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Some dummy question further: no matter which option I use, I need to register some domain to access the web app (SOAP / REST) from the android client device, right? Or am I provided with some IP / domain to refer to the app?

If you use WCF host your webservice on Azure, I suggest you can use the domain name to implement into your Android application.

I have store my application configuration information into Azure Blob Storage. My Android application could get the REST endpoints,domain name,IP and so on information from Azure Blob storage before my application request WCF service on Azure.